# Am trying to get data from an atlas file

Tags: javascript, node.js

am trying to get data from an atlas file the way I do with json files but it's not working, please can I get help

```js
const jsonFile=require("./Assets/AquaSpawn/Aqua_Spawn/aqua spawn all.json")

var bodyMagnitude = jsonFile.skins.default[fishBodyPart.replace(".png", "")][fishBodyPart.replace(".png", "")];
```

Comment: Please provide the contents of your `aqua spawn all.json` file because otherwise we have no way of knowing what your data looks like.

Comment: ok I'll push it in now

Comment: it's a spine json file, it's too large for me to push